# Sculpt brush size lock in 2.8

Tags: sculpting

Where did the brush size lock go for sculpt mode in 2.8???

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sculpt mode>Properties>Brushes>Brush settings>
There is a new icon Which is for "UNIFIED" properties. It is available for strength and radius for the brush.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Example Change Radius Unit]
From what I can tell is you just have to change the Radius Unit to Scene for the scale to stay consistent with the model. Changing it to View will scale the brush according to the user view port.